# AWS AppSync field level resolver possible for mutation?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

Given I have the following GraphQL query to retrieve a user in AWS AppSync:

```
query MyQuery {
    getUser(input: {userId: "01H4N1V2CH93A3WT51PX0NKSYE"}) {
        userId
        name
        address {
            street
            town
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume retrieving the address is expensive, so I've put a separate resolver on the address field. Now when the address field is contained in the query the resolver kicks in and fetches the address, otherwise not. So far so good.

Now I would like to have a mutation for updating the user's name that should return all of the user data:

```
mutation MyMutation {
    updateUserName(input: {userid: "01H4N1V2CH93A3WT51PX0NKSYE", name: "Kevin"}) {
        userId
        name
        address {
            street
            town
        }
    }
}
```

Question: Does AWS AppSync support putting a separate resolver on the address field for the mutation, like for the query?

I couldn't find any documentation on this around the web...

Comment: Normally your address resolver that you created for the `User` type should kick in in both cases. You shouldn't have to do any extra work.